# Generated Slug Overriding Symfony2 Controller Links

Tags: php, symfony

I am having a few problems with my Routing with regards to my new customised CMS. My CMS can generate custom slugs for a page and I have set up the route for this to work. It does so perfectly. However, I also have a help and advice section that has a different URL and is a static page. My routing.yml looks like this: -

```
helpadvice:
        path:       /help-advice
        defaults:   { _controller: FrontBundle:Posts:helpadvice }

frontpage:
    pattern:    /{slug}
    defaults:   { _controller: FrontBundle:Pages:livepages }
    requirements:
        slug:   .+
```

This should work fine but when I visit the page I get an error that it is looking for the page on the database using the slug.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Read: [How to Render a Template without a custom Controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the routes matter. The `frontpage` route is a *catch all route*, so that should be the very last one and you have to move it there. You can check the order with the `router:debug` command.

Comment: Hi 1ed, by being able to find the listed Routes I realised that /{slug} was listed twice under frontpage and livepages. Thanks to your help I changed the name of frontpage to liovepages which is at the bottom of my routing.yml file and it stopped overriding everything else. Thank you for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your routing is wrong?

/{slug} and /help-device are the same route. Your symfony is thinking "help-device" is a slug. Just change /help-advice for /help/advice (for example) or the /{slug} for /slug/{slug} (or something) and check if that solves your problem.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, this did work but ultimately for SEO purposes I wanted to use that particular clean slug so even though it helped, it didn't quite answer my question I'm afraid. The answer below helped me as I realised where the issue was.

Comment: Thank you for your help though... It is very much appreciated.